# Keycloak websocket support

Tags: websocket, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

Good Day. I am developing an IAM system using Keycloak. I have a task to develop an endpoint that will accept websocket requests and produce some kind of logic. I implemented the interface `RealmResourceProvider` and `RealmResourceProviderFactory` and then made an endpoint. However, when I try to establish a connection, I get an exception:

```bash
Subresource for target class has no jax-rs annotations.
```

As follows from the exception, it is necessary to define the get or post annotations, however, when defining them, other exceptions are thrown, such as an incorrect mime type.
I think that it is necessary to implement this endpoint bypassing the standard keycloak path, but I don't know how. I did not find anything in the official documentation of keycloak, nor did I find any examples on the Internet. Any ideas or examples? Does keycloak support such functionality at all? If it's keycloak version 14.00 with Wildfly server 23. Thanks in advance

```
public class WebSocketStreamResourceProviderFactory implements RealmResourceProviderFactory {

  private final static String ID = "state-stream";

  @Override
  public RealmResourceProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
    return new WebSocketStreamResourceProvider(session);
  }

  @Override
  public void init(Scope config) {
    //dont need
  }

  @Override
  public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {
    //dont need
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    //dont need
  }
```

```
public class WebSocketStreamResourceProvider implements RealmResourceProvider {

  private final KeycloakSession session;

  public WebSocketStreamResourceProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
    this.session = session;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getResource() {
    //some objects
    return new WebSocketStreamResource(some objects);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    //dont need
  }
```

```
public class WebSocketStreamResource extends Endpoint {


  @Override
  public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig endpointConfig) {
// some logic

  }
}
```

Comment: I would focus on Keycloak based on Quarkus. Keycloak 20 - September/October 2022: WildFly distribution will be removed

Comment: @JanGaraj Yes, our project is scheduled to upgrade to a distribution kit with quarkus. However, this will not be soon, so I would like to find a workaround